# xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Tags: redis

I'm trying to use `redis-cli` w/ `xargs` to delete keys matching my pattern, yet getting following error:

```
root@543b9f09e6a8:/data# redis-cli -n 0 --scan --pattern ISO:* | xargs redis-cli -n 0 DEL
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
(integer) 0
root@543b9f09e6a8:/data#
```

Please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with -0: `xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty {rest of redis-cli command}`